# Regular expression not matching as expected

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble using regular expressions.

I have the following code:

```
string d = "moveUp(),;moveDown();";
string[] s = Regex.Split(d, ",");
foreach (string line in s)
{
     string line1 = line.Replace("\n", null);
     line1 = line1.Replace("\r", null);
     string pattern = @"^moveUp();$";
     bool a1 = Regex.IsMatch(line1, pattern);
     if (!a1)
     {
         warning.Text = "error";
         return;
     }
}
```

Why is the value of `a1` `false` here?

Comment: A plain old string comparison would be much simpler here than a regex: `!line1.Equals("moveUp();")` You obviously need no wildcards, no groups, no captures, ... why *are* you using a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` has special meaning in regular expression: capturing group.

You have to escape it: `\(\)` to match `()` literally.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the first line from

```
string s="moveUp(),;moveDown();";
```

to

```
string s="moveUp();,moveDown();";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because splitting `moveUp(),;moveDown();` makes: `moveUp()` and `;moveDown();`

The `,` should be swapped with the `;`.